# Renaming txt files with numbers as filenames in cmd

Tags: linux, windows, winforms

i have files and This names the files example :

```
log(2).txt
log(3).txt
log(4).txt
log.txt
```

I want Rename all of them to file names with numbers like:

```
 1.txt
 2.txt
 3.txt
 4.txt
```

system windows or linux

Comment: What code have you tried yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just save this code into a name.bat file in your folder and run the command

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set i=0
for %%a in (*.txt) do (
    set /a i+=1
    ren "%%a" "!i!.new"
)
ren *.new *.txt
```

Here in order to avoid conflicts first the files are named as '.new' extenstion and later it is converted back to '.txt' files.